# angularjs make div readonly - where to put business logic

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a section readonly based on a checkbox. Typical example is primary address and the billing address. The user enters primary address and can chose the billing address to be the same the primary address.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8indaas/j7yzg/) for example.

HTML (primary address):

```
<fieldset ng-model="primaryAdd">
                    <legend>Primary Address:</legend>
                    House#: <input type="text" ng-model="primaryAdd.houseNum"><br>
                    Street: <input type="text" ng-model="primaryAdd.street"><br>
                    State: <input type="text" ng-model="primaryAdd.state"><br>
                    Zip: <input type="text" ng-model="primaryAdd.zip">
</fieldset>
```

HTML (Same as address)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="makeSameAsAddress" ng-model="makeSameAsAddressCheck" ng-click="makeSameAsAddress($event)">Same as above<br/>
```

HTML (Billing Address)

```
<fieldset ng-model="billingAddress">
                    <legend>Billing Address:</legend>   
                    <div>                 
                        <div style="font-size:small">if the address is the same as residence, prefill and make it readonly</div>
                        House#: <input type="text" ng-model="billingAddress.houseNum" ng-readonly="makeSameAsAddressCheck"><br>
                        Street: <input type="text" ng-model="billingAddress.street" ng-readonly="makeSameAsAddressCheck"><br>
                        State: <input type="text" ng-model="billingAddress.state" ng-readonly="makeSameAsAddressCheck"><br>
                        Zip: <input type="text" ng-model="billingAddress.zip" ng-readonly="makeSameAsAddressCheck">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

The fiddle does work. When I click on "Same as above" checkbox, the billing section gets the address from the primary section and is readonly. The question is why I cannot put the ng-readonly on the fieldset or the div surrounding the inputs. I have to put the ng-readonly on all the inputs. I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Maybe I need to create a directive called "makeSameAsPrimaryAndReadOnly". I read that business logic should sit in directives and not HTML directly or the controllers. But I don't see the point of doing this. Unless I was reusing the billing address in multiple places.

Secondly, where is a good place to initialize the model and have a schema to share with other controllers etc? I imagine a factory would be best for this? Thank you.

Angular rocks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directive, but it might be overkill for this purpose.

You can't apply the ng-readonly to the div or the fieldset like it were a css style.  Honestly, I don't think it's too bad the way it is if you only have 4 inputs.

You can simplify the logic for the checkbox (and eliminate the ng-click event) by using a watch expression:

```
$scope.$watch('makeSameAsAddressCheck', function (newv, oldv) {
    if (newv) 
        $scope.billingAddress = $scope.primaryAdd;
    else if (newv !== oldv)
        $scope.billingAddress = angular.copy($scope.primaryAdd);           
});
```

Notice that when you turn the checkbox on, I set both scope variables to reference the same object.  Now when you make modifications to the primary address, it's automatically updated in the billing address.

When you turn the checkbox off, I make a copy of the primary address.  They can now be edited independently.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcSgz/

Business login in controllers is fine.  In fact, that's where it should be.

You can initialize your model in a service, which is created with the "factory" function.

Comment: Thank you for explaining watchers. I was able to add ng-show to div and fieldset. Was hoping the same for ng-readonly.
I would like to pre populate the form/application when it loads by using a web service or a REST api. So I can define a service to do that. I have a factory that defines my model structure and puts it on the scope. I know this is an additional step, but I like the idea of having a separate model layer. And all the business logic goes into watchers (in controllers) or in directives (for more complex dom manipulation). So much to learn! I think I have enough knowledge to start.